# Akka Unbounded Mailbox seems to be bounded

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka

I must be misunderstanding something here.  The docs say the default mailbox is supposed to be unbounded, but just to be sure I added explicit configuration:

```
akka.actor.default-mailbox {
    mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.UnboundedMailbox"
}
```

Yet when I fire off 50 messages as follows:

```
1 to 50 foreach { _ =>
    myActorRef ! "myMessage"
}
```

I get about 15 errors:

```
ActorRefSourceActor - Dropping the new element because buffer is full and overflowStrategy is: [DropNew]
```

What's going on here?

EDIT:

@cmbaxter - Thanks you're right, I over simplified the code a bit too much not realizing which part was actually broken.  The missing pieces of information were:

- `myActorRef` actually refers to a WebSocket actor setup as described in the play docs [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets).  Which as you mentioned, uses an ActorFlow.
- The message to `myActorRef` is not the problem, but it in turn writes to the WebSocket which is where the trouble actually lies.

Comment: I think you are hiding some details here. It seems that you are using Akka Streams and treating your actor as a `Source`. Stream components cannot have unbounded buffering and need a strategy when downstream starts to back pressure like you are seeing here. This has nothing to do with mailbox bounding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand where it's coming from, the fix was fairly trivial.
I just increased the buffer size of the ActorFlow which would normally default to 16, eg:

```
ActorFlow.actorRef(MyActor.props(), 10000)
```